# A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (unable to change SQL Server)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-config

I have an ASP.Net site that's hosted as a shared account. I am getting the error:

```
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error 
occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - 
The specified data could not be decrypted.
```

The info I found online seems to indicate that the issue is the SQL Server is not trusting the certificate (the SSL cert is a valid cert signed by verisign and from the hosting service, not self-signed). However, the hosting service told me:

1. SQL Server has to be set to "Force Protocol Encryption" because it's a shared server
2. They cannot import the certificate or make any changes and won't allow me to do anything on that end either

Is there another solution? Is this a problem with my code? I tried deleting my DLLs from the bin folder and the web.config and just making an aspx page that connects directly to the database but I still get the same error!

Is it possible to fix this? Is it my code that's causing this somehow?

**EDIT: I changed to using the ip address in the connection string and it temporarily started working again but now it is giving me the error again. I'm not sure why it occasionally starts working again and then stops working suddenly. Does anyone know?**

(The code works perfectly on my development server which I host locally)

**The Web Page**

```
<%@ Page language="c#" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Web" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<script runat="server">

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Now insert into database
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]  );

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(  );
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TestTable";
        cmd.ExecuteReader();
        Response.Write( "done" );
    }
    catch (Exception sqlEx)
    {
        Response.Write( sqlEx.ToString() );
    }
}
</script>
```

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>

        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ConnectionString" value="server=mydb.thehostingservice.com;user=dbUser;initial catalog=test;pwd=dbpass" ></add>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting SQL Server to "Force Protocol Encryption" to see if that really does work?

Comment: Exactly what certificate is this?  Where is it coming from and how is SQL Server using it?

Comment: @RBarryYoung The hosting service refuses to change the "Force Protocol Encryption" setting. And they won't give me the ability to do so either

Comment: @RBarryYoung I'm not sure what certificate it's talking about, but I'm assuming it's the site's SSL cert. I based that on the error I get from SQL Server and all the threads online about it.

Comment: The SSL cert for which site?  Your client or their server?  And can you change it to just not use SSL/HTTPS? (I don't see anything in your code above that should require it)

Comment: What versions of things are you using? (SQL Server, C#, and .Net Framework)  Also do you have any security/cryptography libraries added to your solution?

Comment: @RBarryYoung .Net 3.5, SQL Server 2008. And I don't need SSL for the above code because that's just some simple example code. I need SSL for parts of the site.

Comment: I have seen similar errors if SQL Server is not given enough memory.

Comment: @leppie are you sure that's what it is?

Comment: @DonRhummy: No idea, but my issues started happening when I started limiting the memory to SQL Server (via SSMS). And went away when I increased it again. Should be easy enough to test for that.

Comment: @leppie How would I test for that when my hosting service won't allow me to touch SQL Server (other than through direct calls and a query analyzer)? How could I use those tools to do that? Is there a query I could do?

Comment: @DonRhummy: Sorry, no idea. This happened on my dev PC (only 4gb ram...)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a good permanent fix but I was able to finally get it to connect by using the database's IP address and the port in the connection string instead of the database's "web" address. So I replaced "mydb.thehostingservice.com" with "192.168.1.213,1433".

After this, it was able to connect.

But what makes me skeptical this is a permanent solution is that after this I switched back to using "mydb.thehostingservice.com" in the connection string to see if ti would break and that now works too! So this might break on me again in the future.

Previously I had received the error but I deleted my web.config and dlls and that fixed it temporarily - but this latest time of deleting that stuff did not fix it - so I fear this is the same.

**EDIT: It is giving me the error again. That was not the solution.** I'm not sure why it occasionally starts working again and then stops working suddenly. Does anyone know?

Comment: I'm starting to think it's caused by a load balancer, either on DNS, or on SQL Server itself. 
Still a problem in 2020, on sql server v 2012 r2 standard. 
But I find your answer highly interesting; as it coincides with my tests as well. Using a direct IP connection seems to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

My reading of the previous postings and resolutions of this problem on the internet is that the problem   may be on your Client instead of their Server.  Step one to trying to figure this out is to add the following to your connection string:

```
;Use Encryption for Data=True
```

Then see if that fixes the problem, or if it changes the error message.

---

OK, one thing that I noticed is that you have `..;user=..` in your connection string.  Try changing the "user=" to "user id=".

---

I can only think of one other thing to try at this point:  Bring up the SQL configuration utility on your client and right-click on the SQL Native Client protocol and select "Properties".  Then note what the "Force [Protocol] Encryption" is set to, then reverse it.  Now restart everything and try to connect again.

Comment: When I try that in the string, I get `Keyword not supported: 'use encryption for data'.`

Comment: That's odd.  Did you cut and paste it from here?  Because the capitalization should be the same.

Comment: Ok, then try ";Encrypt=Yes" instead.

Comment: Same as original. It was as if I hadn't even included it.

Comment: Hmm, is this: `Keyword not supported: 'use encryption for data'.` the exact error message that you received when you tried my first suggestion?  I ask because I cannot find any instance if this error message on the internet...?  Also what provider are you using (SQL Native Client v?.?), I don't see it specified anywhere.

Comment: I tried making the db calls from a regular http non-ssl page and get the same error! So not sure why I'm getting this.

Comment: I'll try the user id string. could this also be a problem with needing to set the application add medium trust? would you know how to do that in .net 3.5?

Comment: @DonRhummy unfortunately, I am not familiar with how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this happen after upgrading to .NET Core 6. Everything was fine in .Net Core 2.1. I copied out the SQL that was being generated and ran it manually in SSMS. The simple query that Entity Framework generated was returning results that were absolutely huge. 40,000+ records with hundreds and hundreds of fields each. The query was timing out and returning partial results. I assume the broken data cannot be decrypted. I tracked this down to using IQueryable(). Switching the following code

```
private IQueryable<Event> EventQueryable(Guid id) =>
            EventQueryable()
                .Where(evt => evt.Id == id);
Event evt = await _dbContext.EventQueryable(id)
```

to avoid IQueryable

```
Event evt = await _dbContext.Events.Where(e => e.Id == id)
```

Returned a single row almost instantly.